# Shopify Liquid to show banner on date range

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to show banner on product page using date metafield and I am looking for the liquid code

My metafields are below:

```
{{ product.metafields.timer_test.image.value }}

{{ product.metafields.timer_test.fr-date.value }}

{{ product.metafields.timer_test.to-date.value }}
```

How can I make the liquid code on this base?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn all the dates into timestamps (number of seconds), then compare them and see if the "now" timestamp is between the start and end. Just make sure the values in the metafields are properly formatted, for example "Aug 2, 2022".

You can test it [here](https://jumpseller.in/support/liquid-sandbox/).

```
{% assign dateStart = product.metafields.timer_test.fr-date.value | date: '%s' %}
{% assign dateEnd = product.metafields.timer_test.to-date.value | date: '%s' %}
{% assign nowTimestamp = 'now' | date: '%s' %}

{% if dateStart < nowTimestamp and dateEnd > nowTimestamp %}
<img src="{{ product.metafields.timer_test.image.value }}" class="banner">
{% endif %}
```